# Installation kernel modules to specific path

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to try my simple kernel module `hello.ko` on QEMU. I have root filesystem on hdd.img file and compiled kernel in another folder. I run QEMU by this command from directory with sources:

```
   qemu-system-i386 -m 128M -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda" -hda hdd.img
```

How to install my module? Modprobe? But how to specify WHERE to install? As I 
understand, modprobe install module to my host system, not to QEMU-related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing own kernel module into target machine is very similar to installing into current machine:

1. Mount device with root filesystem for target machine. Mount point is referred as `<mount-point>` below.
2. Copy (e.g. with `cp` command) your module file (`hello.ko`) into directory with other kernel's modules, located at `<mount-point>/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/`. It is better to use additional subdirectory `extra/` for 3d-party modules.
3. If you want you module to be loaded with `modprobe` on target machine, you need to use `depmod` command, which has been used for the kernel itself:

   ```
   depmod -b <mount-point>/lib/modules/<kernel-version>
   ```